# Найти количество слов в строке

Tags: sql, sql-server

Показать все товары, название которых состоит из 3-x слов.

```
CREATE TABLE Products
(
    Id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    ProductName VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    Manufacturer VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    ProductCount INT DEFAULT 0,
    Price DECIMAL NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO Products (ProductName, Manufacturer, ProductCount, Price)
VALUES ('iPhone X', 'Apple', 2, 76000),
('iPhone 8 Silver', 'Apple', 2, 51000),
('iPhone 7', 'Apple', 5, 42000),
('Galaxy S9 Black', 'Samsung', 2, 56000),
('Galaxy S8', 'Samsung', 1, 46000),
('Honor 10 Black', 'Huawei', 2, 26000),
('Nokia 8 White', 'HMD Global', 6, 38000);
```

Comment: И что? Где код, где структура таблицы? Мы не экстрасенсы

Comment: Ответ на ваш вопрос можно найти :[тык](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6bf5b/300)

Comment: Вопрос касается MS SQL Server, а не оракла.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41952250/sql-string-counting-words-inside-a-string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если для разделения слов используются только одинарные пробелы, то можно искать через `replace`

```
select * from products
where (len(productname)-len(replace(productname,' ',''))+1)=3
```

Вот тут пример [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/16ac86/6)

Comment: хм...очевидно, кто-то может предложить решение получше) буду рад увидеть)